# `numberOfItemsInSection` only being called after first item in array is added, limiting items to only one

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Currently I have a UICollectionvView which get's it's info from a corresponding UITableView cell like so:

```
//TableView
var knownForArray: [UIImage] = []
var knownForExtendedArray: [CastExtendedData] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = peopleImagesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: knownForCellIdentifier) as! KnownForCell

    print("Known for array count at cell:\(self.knownForArray.count)")

    cell.imageDelegete = self
    cell.knownForExtendedArray = self.knownForExtendedArray
    cell.knownForArray = self.knownForArray
    self.peopleImagesTableView.rowHeight = 150

    return cell
}

//CollectionView 

var knownForArray: [UIImage] = []
var knownForExtendedArray: [CastExtendedData] = []

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("Known for array count collectionview numberOfRowsInSection:\(self.knownForArray.count)")

    return knownForArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = knownForCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: knownForReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! KnownForCollectionViewCell

    if let knownPoster = knownForExtendedArray[indexPath.row].poster{

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

    print("collectionview knownForarray: \(self.knownForArray.count)")

    cell.knownForImages.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "\(baseImageURL)\(knownPoster)"))
    }

  }
  return cell
}
```

By adding a `print` statements, I was able to tell that, as soon as the first item is added to the tableview's `knownForArray`. It triggers the collectionview's `numberOfItemsInSection`, which limits the total items in section to 1.  The tableview's `knownForArray` can have 50+ items, after it's finished retrieving all the JSON data.

Comment: What happens when you add more than 1 item to `knownForArray`? It's also not very clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to have the numberOfItemsInSection for the collectionview cell equal to the total count of the knownForArray

Comment: I think the issue is the numberOfItemsInSection is being called too quickly before all the items in the knownForArray has been appended

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `collectionView.reloadData()` whenever your network call is finished.

Comment: to add to this, it is highly recommended that if you put the reloadData() within the asynchronous HTTP Request, that you do so on the main thread, in order to see the changes on the UI immediately. like so: 

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                })

Comment: @Jay It's more than recommended, it's required in order for it to work properly.